# Intellisense for typings in node_modules

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I crated a lib, that is written in typescript and provides its own typings. The published version in the node_modules basically looks like this:

```
node_modules/
  @scope/
    lib/
       dist/
         index.js
         index.d.ts
         SomeClass.js
         SomClass.d.ts
      package.json
```

where index exports SomeClass.
The package json contains the following:

```
{
  "files": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

Now, when I am trying to use this in a typescript app, I don't get any autocompletion or intellisense. Neither while typing nor when hovering over the full class name.

[image: Cannot find name 'SomeClass']

When I type this manually, I can use the class and autocompletion is available for its properties:

```
import { SomeClass } from '@scope/lib';
```

For other libraries this works, an example:

[image: library with intellisense working]

I wonder, what am I doing wrong? And how can I debug this? I have searched the internet, but did not find any solution to this.

Comment: Well, you don't expect external entities to work without importing them, do you?

Comment: No, of couse not, I want intellisene. I will add a screenshot to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Oh, I can see the problem now. Usually, I restart VSCode (Press F1, then search for "reload") and it helps. But I suppose you've tried that already.

Comment: @marikaner can you provide a link to this package?

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky, yes I have tried this and unfortunately this does not change anything.

Comment: @Skovy unfortunately I can't (yet) because this is not released yet. I only have it in a private registry. Are you looking for something specific?